# For loop for JLabel in GridBagConstraints confusion, GUI displays black symbol instead of days

Tags: java, for-loop, gridbaglayout

Below you will find my code at my attempt to create a GUI in Java for a calendar. I only need to create a month GUI for October. I do not need any active or dynamic setup it simply needs to be static.

It just needs to display the month of October. However, I have ran into issues I am not familiar with that I never ran into just printing out to the terminal.

Using a the AWT, and the Swing components is new for me.

My main issue is that the loop I have created which is supposed to create the days of the calander, is printing out a weird dark shape instead of the numbers.

I know it has something to do with the JLabel, I tried converting the int to a string but I feel like maybe I am missing something that is over my head.

I apologize for all the code but I want you all to see all of it to see if my mistake lays elsewhere.

The mistake is in my loop however  which is right below this.

```java
    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
     for (int y = 2; y <= 6; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 6; x++) {
            layoutConst.gridx = x;
            layoutConst.gridy = y;
            for (int a = 1; a <= 31; a++) {

                layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
                this.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(a)), layoutConst);

            }

        }
     }
```

Here is the rest of the code for the class as well.

```java
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CalendarFrame extends JFrame {

  public CalendarFrame() {



    JLabel month = null;
    GridBagConstraints layoutConst = null;

    month = new JLabel ("October");

    this.setTitle("Monthly Calendar");

    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout() );

    // create gb contstraints
    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();

    layoutConst.gridx = 3;
    layoutConst.gridy = 0;

    layoutConst.insets = new Insets (0,0,0,0);

    this.add(month, layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 0;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("S "), layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 1;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("M "), layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 2;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("T"), layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 3;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("W"), layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 4;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("T"), layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 5;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("F "), layoutConst);

    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst.gridx = 6;
    layoutConst.gridy = 1;
    layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    this.add(new JLabel("S"), layoutConst);

    //GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    layoutConst = new GridBagConstraints();
     for (int y = 2; y <= 6; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 6; x++) {
            layoutConst.gridx = x;
            layoutConst.gridy = y;
            for (int a = 1; a <= 31; a++) {
                //String b = String.valueOf(a);
                layoutConst.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
                this.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(a)), layoutConst);
                //this.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(a)), layoutConst);
                //this.add(new JLabel(b), gbc);
            }

        }
     }




   }// end calendar frame

}// end class
```

Below this is the picture of my output. Why am I getting these weird symbols?

[image]

Comment: You’re adding 31 labels to each cell

Comment: How can I make it so I get 1 - 31 one day in each cell?

Comment: Use a counter to determine the day, then simply keep using the other loops